# DocumentDb Emulator Explorer not showing any collections or data

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The explorer is empty but in to-do list test app the DocumentDB base works fine.

Has anybody a solution for this?

Comment: You really need to edit your question and provide more than that. As written, it's unclear what you're asking. What explorer? What to-do list app? What are the details of your app and connection string?

Comment: I'm talking about the new DocumentDB Emulator, which has an explorer tab in which to view the data in the emulator database. The to-do list test app is a test app for trying the DocumentDB Emulator, provided by Microsoft. It works, data goes in and out in to the emulator DocumentDB database, but the explorer tab in the emulator doesn't show anything.

Comment: Here is a link to the emulator and short instructons:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator

The test app to-do list can be downloaded from a link in the installed emulator.

Comment: Not an answer yet but there is an issue with query explorer that we're currently tracking.   In the interim, you should be able to use the [DocumentDB Studio](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases) to view the data while we work on a fix.

Comment: We have just released a patch that should fix the Query Explorer.  Could you please shut down and restart DocumentDB Local Emulator and see if that fixes it?

Comment: It's working now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, there was an issue with the Query Explorer as part of the DocumentDB Local Emulator.  We have identified the issue and this has been recently fixed.

The patch will automatically (if you have already installed the latest DocumentDB Local Emulator) when you shut down and restart the local emulator.

If there are any issues, you can also workaround this issue by using the [DocumentDB Studio](https://github.com/mingaliu/DocumentDBStudio/releases).